# Some projects not opening in git

Tags: git, github

I have added 5 projects to my git repo , two of my projects naming-server & api-gateway are showing in the git repo but they are opening, I am unable to figure out what i am missing out, Can anyone suggest me on this..
I am attaching the screenshot for refrence , both the projects have data files in them.

[image]

Comment: That looks like they’ve been added as sub modules, is that intentional? Why are multiple projects in the same repo?

Comment: I have experience with monolithic architechture , was practcing microservice ,did it intentionally so that i could get all the services in a one go @AD7six, can you suggest me a proper approach

Comment: Each project = separate repo would be the normal way. Regarding the question If you check the files on disk you’ll likely find `api-gateway/.git` (showing cli output is more helpful than screenshots btw), there’ll be existing questions for how to remove sub modules if that’s your chosen path.

Comment: Note that to add a submodule *correctly*, you will want to use `git submodule add`, not just `git add`.